# Does Mark Watney's pirate line make sense in the film?

Tags: movie, the-martian

In Andy Weir's novel *The Martian*, Mark Watney declares at one point that he's technically a space pirate because

> he is going to commandeer the Ares 4 MAV without explicit permission from NASA.  The reason he doesn't have explicit permission is that the Pathfinder communications circuits were fried in an earlier mishap, cutting off his communication with NASA.  This requires him to undertake his journey to the Ares 4 MAV without external guidance.

In the film, he delivers the same line about being a space pirate; however

> he never loses communication with NASA because the Pathfinder communications are never destroyed.  He has apparent communications with NASA at least up to the time that he leaves the Hab.  So there's no reason he *wouldn't* have explicit permission from NASA (an explicit *order* even) to commandeer the Ares 4 MAV.

Given this disparity between novel and film, does the "space pirate" line actually make sense in the latter?

Comment: No it doesn't. You are right.

Comment: My recollection was that his explanation in the movie was, since the Ares 4 was uninhabited, and he wasn't yet in it, NASA couldn't give him legal permission, yet. Seemed like a Catch-22, you can't legally take it without permission, but you can't be given permission until you're already in it. Actual maritime law, or movie handwaving?  Dunno.

Comment: He doesn't need to mean it literally - it's just a bit of fun in his head. You'd probably be the same if you were the only person on Mars...

Comment: @HorusKol I'd probably be dead because I'm terrible at math.

Comment: One could argue that he's still stealing it, because if NASA revoked their permission, he'd still do it.  His desperation is driving him to take this thing, with or without permission.  It's like the difference between robbing a guy who willingly gives you his wallet and robbing a guy who resists and makes you yank it out of his hands: either way, you're still robbing him.  NASA giving their permission was irrelevant to his plans.  That might not hold up legally, it but makes enough sense for him to claim it.

Comment: He also declares himself the greatest botanist on Mars. And while it's technically true, the actual fact of it is not significant in the slightest. The guy has no entertainment except the stiff he thinks of.

Comment: Space Pirates don't care if they make sense.

Comment: It's better explained in the book. The movie skips most parts (They were both good tho).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just re-watched *The Martian*, and I think a plausible explanation does exist:

### It was only casual permission

In the film, Matt Damon's delivery of the line is very specific: he puts *a lot* of emphasis on the world "explicitly."  It's clear from his delivery that the "explicit" part is the crux of his argument.

> "Nobody *EXPLICITLY* gave me permission to do this..."

Given that he's talking about legal nitpicking, he's likely speaking in terms of legal technicalities.  According to that standard, he probably never got *official* permission to use the Ares 4 MAV.

He likely discussed it with them casually, and he almost certainly got some kind of go-ahead from them, but he couldn't have signed any kind of official documentation and he probably spent his time talking to people who don't *actually* have the clearance required to allow it.  We never see the NASA Director (Jeff Daniels) working the comm, for example.

Obviously no one is going to punish him, but Watney is probably right: **he's taking over the MAV without having signed any waivers, without having agreed to any changes in clearance or rank, and possibly without having spoken directly to anyone in charge**.

It's a legal technicality, but there IS a difference between casual remarks and *explicit* permission.

Comment: OMG he didn't have a health and safety plan

Answer (score 7):

According to [one person it does](http://news.unl.edu/newsrooms/unltoday/article/how-realistic-is-the-martian-unl-experts-weigh-in/):

> Mark Watney’s mission is the third manned expedition to Mars, where he
>   resides in a NASA-built “Hab” and drives a NASA rover on the planet’s
>   surface. In a desperate bid to survive, he eventually decides to try
>   driving the rover to a NASA lander that was sent to Mars in
>   preparation for another manned mission taking place roughly four years
>   after his own.
>
> In the meantime, he gets to thinking about Martian law: There’s an
>   international treaty saying no country can lay claim to anything
>   that’s not Earth. And by another treaty, if you’re not in any
>   country’s territory, maritime law applies. So Mars is “international
>   waters.” NASA is an American nonmilitary organization, and it owns the
>   Hab. So while I’m in the Hab, American law applies. As soon as I step
>   outside, I’m in international waters. Then when I get in the rover,
>   I’m back to American law. Here’s the cool part: I will eventually go …
>   commandeer the Ares 4 lander. Nobody explicitly gave me permission to
>   do this, and they can’t until I’m aboard Ares 4 and operating the comm
>   system. After I board Ares 4, before talking to NASA, I will take
>   control of a craft in international waters without permission. That
>   makes me a pirate! A space pirate!
>
> Watney is referencing the Outer Space Treaty signed by the United
>   States and the former Soviet Union in 1967, said Frans von der Dunk,
>   an Othmer Professor of Space Law at UNL.
>
> “Basically agreed upon by the two giant Cold War adversaries, the idea
>   was to prevent the historic land grabs of colonialist times from
>   extending to outer space – thereby hopefully preventing it from
>   becoming another battleground,” said von der Dunk, a foremost
>   authority on space law. “It is often hailed as the Magna Carta of
>   outer space, meaning it serves as the grand framework treaty providing
>   the overarching legal regime for all human activity … in outer space,
>   based on freedom for all to peacefully explore and use (it).”
>
> Von der Dunk generally agreed with Watney’s interpretation of the
>   treaty, saying that “individual space objects … can be made to fall
>   under the quasi-territorial jurisdiction of the state of registry,
>   just like ships or aircraft registered (on Earth).”
>
> As for Watney’s claim to space piracy?
>
> “One could make that argument, yes,” von der Dunk said. “But I would
>   be careful, for analogies with sea piracy are difficult here. If this
>   qualifies as a real emergency, he might well be in his right to grab
>   any craft that could help him out of dire straits if he is not
>   directly endangering others.”

Comment: But there's still no indication that he lacks explicit permission in the film.  In the novel, the lack of permission comes from the fact that he can't tell NASA what he intends until he uses the Ares 4 MAV to reestablish communication with NASA, but he has to board the MAV in order to do so, which is piracy.  In the film, he's told by NASA to go to the MAV.

Comment: I am not an expert in space law but from my reading of it wouldn't matter if he had communications or not with NASA

Comment: @WayneInYak  "ships or aircraft registered on Earth" would constitute the Hab, the Rover, and the lander as NASA owns all three.   NASA owns the lander.  They tell Mark while he is in the Rover to take the lander which they can do because A: he is in their juristiction and B: it is theirs for them to tell him to take. "Nobody explicitly gave me permission to do this, and they can’t until I’m aboard Ares 4 and operating the comm system" makes no sense in this context.  Your article is correct...when talking about the book.

Comment: I think it is correct when talking about the movie too. The law in question is pretty vague (intentionally) as to what exactly is covered and when it applies. But as I said I am not an expert in the laws governing this area, just reading what others have wrote that are suppose to be experts.

Comment: Yes, but, if you called for a taxi, and whilst waiting for the taxi to arrive you notice another taxi from the same company sitting nearby unused. Taking it would equate to commandeering it. :p

Answer (score 1):

It's just a screw up from the book to the film adaptation. They liked the "Pirate" line so much in the book, they wanted it in the movie but they forgot to include the part where the pathfinder comm circuits were fried in an earlier mishap in the book.

Answer (score 0):

Spoilers AHEAD

> Basically the rover is nasa equipment, in the book he loses communication with them, so he must commandeer that vehicle which is outside of the HAB which is also NASA property, no country can lay claim to mars soil which makes it international waters, and they didnt give him instructions to do so, so he essentially stole the rover to make the trip to ARES IV.

.

> This makes him a space pirate.

.

> In the film however they leave out the part where he shorted out pathfinder, so its a little confusing to someone who didnt read the book, but its essentially the same line.

.

> The pathfinder problem is the only thing I felt like they really dropped the ball on, its a plot device that really connects you to a man with noone to talk to, who gets to finally email people, which explains the ending when hes crying when he hears the crews voices.

Comment: Yeah, plus the fact that after that it all depended on him to figure out how to prepare for the trip and get past the obstacles on the way: he could no longer rely on the remote experts of NASA.  I understand the movie had to leave stuff out (because it would have been a lot less commercial at 4-5hrs long!) but that should have been squeezed in (IMO).